# Light fitting appears stuck to ceiling

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, ceiling

I'm trying to open up this light fitting but it appears that it's absolutely stuck. I tried twisting as hard as I can locations (1), (2) and (3) in the image and I wasn't able to.

Does anyone have ideas on how to open this one up so that I can change the light bulb inside?

I've never opened it up since I'm a tenant.

[image: Light Fitting]

Comment: call your landlord

Comment: Is there a screw in the 2 o’clock position or is that a reflection? 
Are you turning the correct direction? Counter clockwise to loosen. 
Lefty loosy righty tighty it would not be the first time I was called to a job that the customer was turning the wrong way.

Comment: Usually the plate on the ceiling is held to the ceiling by two screws threading into the ceiling box. The glass bowl is held to a threaded shaft by a center nut accessible from below. Turn the nut CW to loosen.

Comment: Hold the glass dome (2) and turn the nut (3).  Its probably hard to turn since those things are rarely removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixture and the globe should stay where they are.

Below, you've got a stem, a washer, and a nut.  When you twist the bottom trim piece counter-clockwise, you should find the nut and washer inside of that.  But hold on to the globe just in case the other parts are missing.

Comment: The trim may _be_ the nut. Regardless, this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a pliers on the center nut you have labeled 3.

If it feels like it is going to snap or break, call the landlord as suggested by jsotola

Comment: Be careful not to drop the glass bowl when you unscrew the center nut holding it on. Ask the landlord if he wants to do this himself. It is very easy to drop that glass bowl.

Comment: You aren't going to get a pliers to grab that cap nut without mangling it. I would not do that.

Comment: True, but sometimes, it's the only alternative.  And it's up high where no one well see it.